# Fatal exception could not execute method by clicking on a button

Tags: android, exception, button, onclick

I created a button for pause the mediaplayer. I have 7 different media-files, that are running one by one. Now I got these exception, if I click on my pausebutton.

```
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456):     ... 11 more
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456):     at de.basti12354.tage.uebungen.Tag1.verlaufKlick(Tag1.java:112)
03-28 20:06:34.302: E/AndroidRuntime(3456):     ... 14 more
```

My verlaufKlick-method:

```
 public void verlaufKlick(View view) {

    if (uebung.isPlaying()) {
        uebung.pause();

    }
    if (uebung2.isPlaying()) {
        uebung2.pause();

    }
    if (uebung3.isPlaying()) {
        uebung3.pause();

    }
    if (uebung4.isPlaying()) {
        uebung4.pause();

    }
    if (uebung5.isPlaying()) {
        uebung5.pause();

    }
    if (uebung6.isPlaying()) {
        uebung6.pause();

    }
    if (uebung7.isPlaying()) {
        uebung7.pause();

    } else {
        uebung.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: Which is the 112th line of your Tag1.java file?

Comment: }    thats it?????        Its the ending brace of if (uebung5.isPlaying())

Comment: Now I tested it again and get 03-28 20:23:25.082: E/AndroidRuntime(3515): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 20:23:25.082: E/AndroidRuntime(3515):  at de.basti12354.tage.uebungen.Tag1.verlaufKlick(Tag1.java:100)